# json-parsing errors at run time

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

I am trying to send some sign up information to a php server from my *Android* app.

I have two classes: ***RegisterActivity*** and ***JSONParser***. 
While I'm trying to run this programs there is some errors like this:

`Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value not of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject" and "android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)`

Here is my code:

***RegisterActivity.java***

```
public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    EditText username;
    EditText email;
    EditText password;
    EditText RePass;

    private static String url_create_product = "http://oranz.co/pmdtest/index.php";

            private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "sucess";
            @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set View to register.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.register);
        Button registerscreen=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCntnueRegister);
        // Listening to Login Screen link

        email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.reg_email);
        password =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.reg_password);
        username =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.reg_username);
        RePass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.rereg_password);
        EditText passwords=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.reg_password);
        passwords.setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());
        EditText repasswords = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rereg_password);
        repasswords.setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());



        registerscreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                if(email.getText().toString().equals("")&&password.getText().toString().equals("")&&username.getText().toString().equals("")&&RePass.getText().toString().equals(""))
                {                                        
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Please Enter a valed data. !", duration);       
                    toast.show();
                }
                else if(email.getText().toString().equals("")||password.getText().toString().equals("")||username.getText().toString().equals("")||RePass.getText().toString().equals(""))
                {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Please check any field is blank. !", duration);       
                    toast.show();
                }
                else if(password.getText().toString().compareTo(RePass.getText().toString())==0)
                {
                Intent k = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ContinueRegister.class);
                startActivity(k);

                new CreateNewUser().execute();

                }
                else
                {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Password matching is failed. !", duration);       
            toast.show();


                }
            }
            });
      TextView loginScreen = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link_to_login);

      loginScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent m = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(m);

        }
    });
    }
            class CreateNewUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
super.onPreExecute();
pDialog = new ProgressDialog(RegisterActivity.this);
pDialog.setMessage("Creating Product..");
pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
pDialog.setCancelable(true);
pDialog.show();
}

protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
String Username = username.getText().toString();
String Email = email.getText().toString();
String Password = password.getText().toString();

List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Username", Username));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Email", Email));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Password",Password));


// getting JSON Object
// Note that create product url accepts POST method

JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
"POST", params);

// check log cat fro response
Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());                  
// check for success tag
try {
int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

if (success == 1) {
// successfully created user
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),FinishSignupActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
// closing this screen
finish();
} else {
// failed to create user
}
} catch (JSONException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}

return null;
                    }

                /**
                 * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
                 * **/
                protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
// dismiss the dialog once done
pDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
}
```

***JSONParser.java***:

```
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET method
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           


        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

Comment: May i know what is the response your server(i.e, from that url) when you invoke it from any browser.

Comment: i didn't get any response from the server side

Comment: If you didn't receive any response while you invoke it from your Browser, then how can you use it in your client side. can you post your server side code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the android emulator crash there is no mistakes in the programs.